# The background-color of the body changes when I scroll past the bottom/top of the page

Tags: css, next.js, background, background-color

I have a next.js app and the background-color of the body is set to black.
globals.css:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
```

But this is what happens in the browser when I scroll down past the bottom of the page:
[image]

Notice that the background is purple (as is the background-color of my "Layout.tsx") which is inside of the body.

This is the body as displayed in the Developer Tools of Chrome:
[image]

This is the `layout-main` as loaded from "Layout.tsx" displayed in the Developer Tools of Chrome:
[image]

So how do I get the black body background to extend throughout the entire background, even the overflow when I scroll down past the bottom?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

For me it works when I set a `background-color` for the `html` tag with the same color value as for the `body` tag, i.e. in your case that would be `html { background-color: black; }`

Comment: I tried doing html { background-color: black; } but I got the same result